# How to use Google Api to upload to a single Youtube channel on a User-less app

Tags: swift, oauth-2.0, youtube, youtube-data-api

I'm building an app that will allow users to upload videos to my Youtube channel. I have checked online about using Google Api to access the data/upload videos, but all references and examples seem to assume videos will be uploaded to the user's youtube channel, hence the process always involves using OAuth to gain approval from the user.

However, in my case the only youtube channel all users will access is mine. And I'm not even asking them to create an account on my app to upload the videos. Is there a way to do this directly from the app.

My app is an iOS app, but if you have a solution in any other language, I welcome your suggestion.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem not so long ago. Youtube Documentation doesnt make it easy. Even though you getting access to your own Youtube channel, You still need to be authenticated using OAuth. Google makes hard for you to be vulnerable to attacks.

My solution is using a server side(API) application. What you can then do is make your iOS app hit the API.
So the tricky thing is getting the refresh token. Its hardly documented anywhere. What you can then do is follow documentation of your preferred language for the API.

The documentation can be found here https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/auth/server-side-web-apps

Get the Refresh token:

**Step 1** : Hit this url in the browser https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=**ClientID_Here**&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob&scope=https://gdata.youtube.com&response_type=code&access_type=offline

It will make you log in using your youtube credential which is your google account.
You will then have to agree for google to access your account by clicking allow.
At the end it will give you a code.

**Step 2** : You should then authenticate using a clientless platform.

(eg instead of browser) Use curl instead. (There plenty of 3 minute tutorials on how to use curl)
Hit this url endpoint :

curl https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token -d "code=**CodeFromGoogleOAuth**&client_id=**ClientIDHere**&client_secret=**ClientSecretHere**&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob&grant_type=authorization_code"

You should then get a refresh token in the response.

There are alot of examples of how to upload from then on like
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/dotnet

In the example above you have to avoid using the **GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker** use Googles one instead. Look for RefreshToken Field

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to allow third parties to upload videos to a single YouTube account with the YouTube Data API, and that is by design. See [this Google Blog](https://youtube-eng.googleblog.com/2012/02/video-uploads-from-your-sites-community_15.html), explaining "It’s tempting to design a system in which all videos are uploaded to a single “master” YouTube account, but this is always the wrong approach."

A potential workaround is to use [YouTube Direct Lite](https://code.google.com/archive/p/youtube-direct-lite/), which allows you to easily build and moderate a playlist on your YouTube account comprised of videos uploaded by your users on their accounts.